# How do I send SIGKILL on cygwin in GNU Screen?

Tags: windows, unix, terminal, cygwin, gnu-screen

I have recently started using GNU screen on cygwin, but the functionality to terminate a foreground process with CTRL-C does not seem to work when there is an active screen session. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to terminate in the screen it-self, you could try the following shortcut:

```
Ctrl-A, k
```

It will send kill signal to the process (additional confirmation is required).

Press `Ctrl-A, ?` to see more options.

---

Other methods:

You can suspend the job:

```
Control-Z
```

and it'll return you the job ID of that process

To continue the process in foreground, you can run:

```
fg
```

In the background:

```
bg
```

If you want to kill it:

```
kill -9 %1
```

(replace 1 with your job ID).

Note: Don't forget about % sign, otherwise you'll kill something else.

Comment: Thanks for the response - unfortunately this didn't work when I tried it though. Control-Z did not seem to suspend the job - the screen session just hangs when I press that. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: updated the answer.